# encoding and decoding a string to binary or hex in python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, character-encoding

i am making a program for me to use in school (on a public server) and some people are changing it and ruining my passwords that are stored in it, could someone please tell me how to convert a string to binary or hex and vice-versa so that people cant see the passwords bear in mind that the people in school are not so brilliant at coding and will be fooled by something quite simple i also dont think that i have the rights to install things on the school computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the fact, that you should not store your passwords so accessible, the [base64](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/base64.html) module does exactly what you want.

Here an example:

```
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode

mypw = "mypassword".encode()     # needs to be a binary-string
encrPW = b64encode(mypw)         # equals b'bXlwYXNzd29yZA=='
assert mypw == b64decode(encrPW) # decoding results in the password
strPW = mypw.decode()            # the python-string representation of the password
                                 # (most possibly the one you need later on)
```